# DataFrame.values on selected column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following error when i try to get not all values but only specified column. I think the error comes from the column I specify after `.values`
Any help would be appreciated.

`supp_bal` dataframe:

```
          circulating_supply  total_supply
currency                                  
0xBTC                4758600      20999984
1337             26456031141   29258384256
1SG                  2187147      22227000
1ST                 85558370      93468691
1WO                 20981450      37219452
1X2                        0       3051868
2GIVE              521605983     521605983
42                        41            41
611                   478519        478519
777                        0   10000000000
A                   26842657     278273649
AAA                 15090818     397000000
```

`pos_bal` dataframe:

```
                      2019-07-23  2019-07-24
 app_vendor_id currency                        
 3             1WO           2604      2304
               ABX             44      44
               ADH            822      82
               ALX             25      200
               AMLT          3673      367
               BCH            -41      -26
```

my code:

```
f = pos_bal.index.get_level_values('currency')
supp_bal['circulating_supply'].loc[f].values['circulating_supply']
```

error:

```
   pos_bal['circulating_supply'] = supp_bal['circulating_supply'].loc[f].values['circulating_supply']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: What's `circulating_supply`?

Comment: try this:  `pos_bal['circulating_supply'] = supp_bal.loc[f, 'circulating_supply']`

Comment: @Andy L Thank you. I tried this there is no error but it output Nan instead of values from `supp_bal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the column name after `values`, 
this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
supp_bal = pd.read_csv('D:\\supp_bal.csv', header=0)
pos_bal = pd.read_csv('D:\\pos_bal.csv', header=0)
supp_bal = supp_bal.set_index('currency')
pos_bal = pos_bal.set_index(['app_vendor_id', 'currency'])
display(supp_bal)
display(pos_bal)
f = pos_bal.index.get_level_values('currency')
pos_bal['circulating_supply']= supp_bal['circulating_supply'].loc[f].values
display(pos_bal)
```

The output

```
          circulating_supply  total_supply
currency                                  
0xBTC                4758600      20999984
1337             26456031141   29258384256
1SG                  2187147      22227000
1ST                 85558370      93468691
1WO                 20981450      37219452
1X2                        0       3051868
2GIVE              521605983     521605983
42                        41            41
611                   478519        478519
777                        0   10000000000
A                   26842657     278273649
AAA                 15090818     397000000


                        7/23/2019  7/24/2019
app_vendor_id currency                      
3             1WO            2604       2304
              ABX              44         44
              ADH             822         82
              ALX              25        200
              AMLT           3673        367
```

Final `pos_bal`

```
                        7/23/2019  7/24/2019  circulating_supply
app_vendor_id currency                                          
3             1WO            2604       2304          20981450.0
              ABX              44         44                 NaN
              ADH             822         82                 NaN
              ALX              25        200                 NaN
              AMLT           3673        367                 NaN
```

Note, in the data you provided, only `1WO` appears in both DataFrames, that's why the other rows are all `NaN`.

btw, I have pandas `0.24.2`.

Comment: Thank you. I have the following error with this code.   
`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: interesting, it works for me. See my updated answer. Do you have different data or code there?

Comment: @NailZ I don't understand. I am confused as I have the same data structure except that the data are longer

Comment: @mamadede Do you mind to share the data? It's hard to debug without the data that cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
f = pos_bal.index.get_level_values('currency')
supp_bal['circulating_supply'].loc[f]
```